# Returning the location of variables in a range of a pandas dataframe column where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have a column in a dataframe, `df[Stress]`. I want to return the location of the rows in the column where the value stored is less than a variable, `load_drop`, but only within a certain range of the column, stated by `first` and `last`. I figured I could use `np.where` to find the locations, but so far I'm returning an empty array when I run the code. Here is what I have so far:

```
df = {'Stress': [1,2,3,6,7,8,10,12,14,20,19,17,15,13,12,10,8,7,6,4,1,0]

first = 10
last = 18
drop = 11

life_array = np.where(df['Stress'].iloc[first:last] < drop)

print (life_array)

[]
```

Ideally, my desired output would be this:

```
print(life_array)

0  15
1  16
2  17
3  18
```

Which is the the location of the rows where the condition is met. Can I use `np.where` and `iloc` in such a fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC need 2 steps - first filter by position and then by mask:

```
s =  df['Stress'].iloc[first:last]
life_array = s[s < drop]

print (life_array)
15    10
16     8
17     7
Name: Stress, dtype: int64
```

If need indices:

```
first = 10
last = 18
drop = 11
s =  df['Stress'].iloc[first:last + 1]
life_array = s.index[s < drop].tolist()

print (life_array)
[15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and it works, but I've realised it's not really what I want - I don't want the value contained, just the index location where the item is contained. I've edited the output to better show this!

Comment: @MurrayRoss - then use `life_array = s.index[s < drop]`